# What does "-" before an argument to "head" do?

Tags: bash, shell, unix-head

I have a simple code here but am having some trouble understanding it.

```
$ more $1 | head -$2 | tail -1
```

For the second parameter, I am running a test txt

```
$ more joe.txt
i am trying
something
else
to
see
if
head
works
the way
it
should
work
```

When I run the script I get the error:

```
$ ./sample.sh jad.txt joe.txt
head: invalid option -- 'j'
Try 'head --help' for more information.
```

It seems to work when I remove the `-` in front of the `$2`.

This is a practice question I found online and I doubt they made a mistake with this one. So either I'm missing something here am doing something wrong.

When I run it without the `-` in front of `$2` I get this:

```
./sample.sh jad.txt joe.txt
it
```

My questions here are:

1. Why does it print "it" only when `tail -1` is used? To my understanding tail prints the last 10 lines. So what does the `-1` do?
2. Is the `-` symbol supposed to do something in front of the `$2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-` before a parameter usually means that it's a short (one character) option to the program. `--` usually means that it's a long (multiple characters) option. This only by convention though. There are lots of exceptions.

So, when running:

```
./sample.sh jad.txt joe.txt
```

your line

```
more $1 | head -$2 | tail -1
```

becomes:

```
more jad.txt | head -joe.txt | tail -1
```

And that makes `head` complain. You've given it the option `-joe.txt` which is interpreted as the short option `-j` but `head` doesn't have a `-j` option.

> So what does the `-1` do?

`tail -1` means print the last `1` line(s) from the input.
`tail -2` means print the last `2` line(s) from the input.
etc...
`head -1` means print the first `1` lines(s) from the input.
`head -2` means print the first `2` lines(s) from the input.
etc...

Comment: so does that mean the "-" in front of the $2 is a mistake since its taking it as -j ?

Comment: @MichaelBacha Yes `-$2` is a mistake unless `$2` contains a valid option for `head`, like a number.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a mistake if you invoke it correctly (assuming this is the output you expect):

```
./sample.sh joe.txt 5
see
./sample.sh joe.txt 4
to
./sample.sh joe.txt 3
else
```

what it's a mistake is not checking for valid options in `sample.sh`

You should do something like

```
#! /bin/bash

usage() {
    printf 'usage: %s file number\n' "$0" >&2
    exit 1
}

if [[ $# != 2 ]]
then
    usage
fi

re='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ "$2" =~ $re ]]
then
    printf 'ERROR: not a number: %s\n' "$2" >&2
    usage
fi

more "$1" | head -n $2 | tail -1
```